# How to batch import files into the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 20 files that I want to put in separate tables. All the tables have the same schema though. I was wondering if there is a good way to do this besides using SQL Server Import/Export Wizard (which I believe is targeted towards single file imports).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What types of files are they?

Comment: They are delimited files that I dumped using `sqlcmd` on a different database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your best bet and definitely the easiest way would be using BULK INSERT.

See here for more information and implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) is probably the easiest way to import those files